# javascript date localization works only in debug mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, localization

I'm working on a react native application and i want to localize the month and week day names. For that i have written functions as below

```
export function setSectionTitle(title: string, locale: string): string {
  const sectionTitle =
    weekDayTranslation(
      moment(Number(title)).format('DD'),
      getMonthNum(moment(Number(title)).format('MMMM')),
      locale,
    ) +
    ', ' +
    moment(Number(title)).format('DD') +
    ' ' +
    monthTranslation(getMonthNum(moment(Number(title)).format('MMMM')), locale);

  return sectionTitle;
}
```

here for title i'm getting time in miliseconds Ex: 1618165800000  , and for locale i'm getting a string Ex: 'en-US' .

There are my other helper functions

```
export function monthTranslation(monthNum: number, country_locale: string): string {
  const objDate = new Date();
  objDate.setDate(1);
  objDate.setMonth(monthNum - 1);

  const locale = country_locale,
    month = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: 'long' });

  return month;
}

export function weekDayTranslation(day: string, monthNum: number, country_locale: string): string {
  const objDate = new Date();
  objDate.setDate(parseInt(day));
  objDate.setMonth(monthNum - 1);
  const translatedDay = objDate.toLocaleString(country_locale, { weekday: 'short' });
  return translatedDay;
}

export function getMonthNum(monthName: string): number {
  const monthNum = parseInt(moment().month(monthName).format('M'));
  return monthNum;
}
```

The issue i'm facing is in debug mode this works perfectly. But when the debug mode is removed the date is shown like `'Wed Apr 7 11:03:10 2021, 07 Thu Apr 1 11:03:10'` where as i want to display it as `Wed 07 April` which works when in debug mode. What is the reason for this and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. So instead of using `toLocalString` , we can use moment to format it to correct format like

```
moment(objDate)
```

For example

```
moment(objDate).locale(country_locale).format('MMMM');
```